# PHP cut GET request param

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, request

In my PHP application I use this code to get request

```
$this->request->get
```

this return all data

```
Array
(
[rt] => extension/dump
[type] => xls
[controller] => list/product
[s] => administration
[token] => s7KO9PkoPmgpQmZjPQOimTbdKMB85uGa
[filters] => {&quot;_search&quot;:true,&quot;nd&quot;:1542700897278,&quot;rows&quot;:20,&quot;page&quot;:1,&quot;sidx&quot;:&quot;date_modified&quot;,&quot;sord&quot;:&quot;desc&quot;,&quot;filters&quot;:&quot;{\&quot;groupOp\&quot;:\&quot;AND\&quot;,\&quot;rules\&quot;:[{\&quot;field\&quot;:\&quot;name\&quot;,\&quot;op\&quot;:\&quot;cn\&quot;,\&quot;data\&quot;:\&quot;Lemon 
[Eucalyptus\&quot;}]}&quot;}] => 
)
```

However next code cut the data

```
$this->request->get['filters']
```

returned only part of data (see the end of 'filters' are removed)

```
{&quot;_search&quot;:true,&quot;nd&quot;:1542700897278,&quot;rows&quot;:20,&quot;page&quot;:1,&quot;sidx&quot;:&quot;date_modified&quot;,&quot;sord&quot;:&quot;desc&quot;,&quot;filters&quot;:&quot;
{\&quot;groupOp\&quot;:\&quot;AND\&quot;,\&quot;rules\&quot;:[{\&quot;field\&quot;:\&quot;name\&quot;,\&quot;op\&quot;:\&quot;cn\&quot;,\&quot;data\&quot;:\&quot;Lemon
```

Is any workaround to get full data inside 'filters'? 
Converting object to array is not help

UPDATE:
js console output

```
{_search: false, nd: 1542700894743, rows: 20, page: 1, sidx:    "date_modified", …}
filters: "{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"name","op":"cn","data":"Lemon & Eucalyptus"}]}"
nd: 1542700897278
page: 1
rows: 20
sidx: "date_modified"
sord: "desc"
_search: true

Request URL: http://blablabla&filters={%22_search%22:true,%22nd%22:1542700897278,%22rows%22:20,%22page%22:1,%22sidx%22:%22date_modified%22,%22sord%22:%22desc%22,%22filters%22:%22{\%22groupOp\%22:\%22AND\%22,\%22rules\%22:[{\%22field\%22:\%22name\%22,\%22op\%22:\%22cn\%22,\%22data\%22:\%22Lemon%20&%20Eucalyptus\%22}]}%22}
```

Request Method: GET

Is it somehow related to ampersand?

Comment: Could you post the actual parameters copied and pasted from your browser's address bar please?

Comment: Have you tried comparing `$this->request->get` and actual `$_GET`? Maybe it's your parser that fails?

Comment: @Justinas , $_GET["filters"] return the same. Cut result to Lemon... last part is missing

Comment: Check your php.ini and tell if value of `max_value_length` does not exceeds your query string. Also note that query string starts with `?` and not with `&`

Comment: `ini_get('max_value_length')` return empty value

Comment: This really depends on how you're reading / displaying these results. It also seems very strange to have your request parameters HTML encoded. I suspect one or both of _"you're viewing it incorrectly"_ and _"something is manipulating the data in a bad way before you read it"_

Comment: Ah, you don't appear to be URL encoding the `&` in `"Lemon & Eucalyptus"`. How are you generating this request data?

Comment: the request is generated by software so I cant control it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're creating the URL and query parameters in JS, you need to [encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) all parameters for use in a URL.

In your case...

```js
const filters = {
  "groupOp": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "field": "name",
      "op": "cn",
      "data": "Lemon & Eucalyptus"
    }
  ]
}

const url = `http://blablabla?filters=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filters))}`

document.write(`<pre>${url}</pre>`)
```

Notice the `&` in `"Lemon & Eucalyptus"` has become `%26`

---

An extra concern is that something is HTML-encoding your request parameters. You should not be doing that unless you are specifically displaying the information in an HTML document.